# Hiding/Showing hyperlink under a dynamic condition

Tags: jsp, controller, hide, dynamic-variables

I'm developing a review website, and allowing users to delete their own reviews...

```
    <a  href=# style="display:{${review.userId}==${User} hide? 'none' : 'block' }">Delete</a>
```

so i'm using this code to compare between the id of the user who wrote the review and the logged in user, if he's the one .. he can see the hyperlink, otherwise he won't be able to see it.... but it doesn't work !!.. the logged in user can see all the delete hyperlinks

when i run the code, this is what appears in the browser...

```
  <a href="#" style="display:{7==7 hide? 'none' : 'block' }">Delete</a>
```

am i doing it right ?

please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using  tag from the JSTL.

```
<c:if test="${review.userId == User}">
     <a href="#">Delete</a>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thank youuuu Nikhil,,, it worked :))) ...
but i read that 
The comparison needs to be evaluated inside EL, not outside so i changed it to <c:if test="${review.userId==User}">
     <a href="#">Delete</a>
    </c:if>

Comment: You are right. Made that mistake in a hurry. Edited my answer as well. Do you mind marking it as the correct answer?